# DirectX for Skyrim fails to Install

Tags: windows-7, directx

I'm trying to install Skyrim SE on Steam and it says that it's missing a DirectX file. So I run the DirectX installer and get the following error:

> An internal system error occurred. Please refer to DXError.log and
>   DirectX.log in your Windows folder to determine problem.

The **DXError.log** file:

> [03/03/19 17:49:44] module: dxupdate(Mar 30 2011), file: dxupdate.cpp,
>   line: 2409, function: RunProcess
>
> Failed API:   CreateProcess() Error: (193) - %1 is not a valid Win32
>   application.
>
> [03/03/19 17:49:44] module: dxupdate(Mar 30 2011), file: dxupdate.cpp,
>   line: 3426, function: InstallEXE
>
> RunProcess() failed.
>
> [03/03/19 17:49:44] module: dxupdate(Mar 30 2011), file: dxupdate.cpp,
>   line: 5829, function: DirectXUpdateInstallPlugIn
>
> InstallEXE() failed.
>
> [03/03/19 17:49:44] module: dsetup32(Mar 30 2011), file: dxupdate.cpp,
>   line: 280, function: CSetup::InstallPlugIn
>
> DirectXUpdateInstallPlugIn() failed.
>
> [03/03/19 17:49:44] module: dsetup32(Mar 30 2011), file: setup.cpp,
>   line: 1727, function: CSetup::SetupForDirectX
>
> InstallPlugIn() failed.

This is a completely clean copy of Windows 7 x64 Professional, what do I do to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out DirectX installers apparently do *not* like custom My Documents paths (E.g. `D:\My Documents` instead of `C:\Users\John`). I switched to a different Windows profile user and the installer worked just fine.